# How to calculate number of zeros, ones and minus ones for each date in a table using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I want to calculate number of zeroes, ones and minus ones for each specific date in the following table using MySQL, what is the query to to do this?

[image]

Comment: Readers are often interested in what people have tried, so when you ask your next question, would you add this? Gordon, who has supplied an answer below, is one of the most helpful people here, but I am sometimes afraid that answering questions like this will encourage posters not to make an effort with their own learning.

Comment: It looks like `sub1` through to `sub6` are subject marks for each student (pass, fail and intermediate?). Would they be better in another table, with a many:many table in between?

Answer (score 0):

You would use boolean expressions to count up the number.  In MySQL, this is easy, because boolean expressions are treated as integers in a numeric context.  So, you can do:

```
select dob,
       ((sub1 = 0) + (sub2 = 0) + (sub3 = 0) + (sub4 = 0) + (sub5 = 0) + (sub6 = 0)
       ) as num_zeros,
       ((sub1 = 1) + (sub2 = 1) + (sub3 = 1) + (sub4 = 1) + (sub5 = 1) + (sub6 = 1)
       ) as num_ones,
       ((sub1 = -1) + (sub2 = -1) + (sub3 = -1) + (sub4 = -1) + (sub5 = -1) + (sub6 = -1)
       ) as num_minusones
from t;
```

If `dob` is not unique and you need to sum them, then there would be aggregation:

```
select dob,
       sum((sub1 = 0) + (sub2 = 0) + (sub3 = 0) + (sub4 = 0) + (sub5 = 0) + (sub6 = 0)
       ) as num_zeros,
       sum((sub1 = 1) + (sub2 = 1) + (sub3 = 1) + (sub4 = 1) + (sub5 = 1) + (sub6 = 1)
       ) as num_ones,
       sum((sub1 = -1) + (sub2 = -1) + (sub3 = -1) + (sub4 = -1) + (sub5 = -1) + (sub6 = -1)
       ) as num_minusones
from t
group by dob;
```

Comment: Isn't that kind of question too broad, as the OP has provided no effort?